# Is there a means to change the color temperature in the video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, color-management

Other video editors have the tab known as temperature. It has an orangeish sepia like effect on one end and a cool blue on the other. I am wondering where this is in the blender video editor, or how to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

In the sidebar panel, among the Modifiers, there is for ex. a white balance modifier which can be used to auto-change the color temperature(after selecting a white spit in the image). Alternatively, there are other modifiers to change the colors.

If you need color scopes, you can add multiple Preview areas in their headers, change the Display Modes to ex. vector scope etc.